# Setting Stash name as {entry_id}

Tags: stash

Having some issues here, not sure if it's even possible.

Template one lists one entry. I want to set a variable and make its name the entry_id of that entry, to be used to validate on the next template based on the same entry.

Template two, I want to match a url segment to the variable. But i need to get the variable name from that same entry, so need to use the {entry_id} in the stash get tag.

I am getting funny results, where it only works if the {entry_id} tag apears anywhere inside the channel:entries loop. If i remove that single tag then the conidional always fails.

I am using EEv2.9.2 and Stash 2.5.8

My code:

Template One:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="whitepapers" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" parse="inward"}

{exp:stash:set_value name="{entry_id}" value="{current_time format="%d%Y%g%i%s"}" scope="user" save="yes"}    

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Template Two:

```
        {exp:channel:entries channel="whitepapers" url_title="{segment_3}" dynamic="no" limit="1" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" parse="inward"}

        {exp:stash:parse process="end"}

        {if "{segment_5}" == "{exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}'}"}
        success
        {/if}

    {/exp:stash:parse}

    {exp:stash:parse process="end"}

        {if "{segment_5}" != "{exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}'}"}
        fail
        {/if}

    {/exp:stash:parse}

{!-- ALWAYS FAIL'S UNLESS THE {entry_id} TAG APPEARS IN THIS CHANNEL ENTRIES LOOP ANYWHERE --}

        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding scope="user" to your stash:get:

```
{if segment_5 == "{exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}'}"}
```

(Don't think you need to add quotes & brackets for segment_5 for 2.9+, or parse="inward" for your outer channel:entries.)

If that doesn't work, also try without wrapping with stash:parse, or at least take off the process="end" so that the conditional is parsed inline instead.

---

UPDATE:

Version 1 or 2 below should work. The first grabs the stash variable but doesn't output it, so it's available for the conditionals. The second is if you use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee).

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="whitepapers" 
    url_title="{segment_3}" 
    dynamic="no" 
    limit="1" 
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
}

    {!--version 1:--}
    {exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}' scope='user' output="no"}

    {if segment_5 == "{exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}'}"}
        success
    {/if}

    {if segment_5 != "{exp:stash:get name='{entry_id}'}"}
        fail
    {/if}

    {!--version 2:--}
    {exp:switchee variable="stash:{entry_id}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="{segment_5}"}
            match
        {/case}
        {case default="yes"}
            no match 
        {/case}    
    {/exp:switchee}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried all of the above with no avail. Very odd indeed.

Comment: See if the updated answer helps.

Comment: Cheers that worked, I originally had the stash:get you added into in version 1, I just didn't think to add output="no" to hide it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!